# How to draw this?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw this figure:

[image]

How can one draw this and include the angles in there? Moreover, how does one include the “arcs” notations for the angles?

Comment: If you are using TikZ, `usetikzlibrary{angles}` and see page 568 or the pgf manual).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from `angles`, as mentioned by John Kormylo, you may want to use `calc`. Then it is straightforward to construct the pic (up to an overall length scale, which is not fixed by the data).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[angle eccentricity=1.5,angle radius=1cm]
   (0,0) coordinate[label=below left:$C$] (C)
   (0,pi) coordinate[label=above left:$B$] (B) 
   (10:5) coordinate (auxC1) (40:5) coordinate (auxC2) 
   ($(B)+(-10:5)$) coordinate (auxB1)
   ($(B)+(-30:5)$) coordinate (auxB2)
   (intersection of B--auxB1 and C--auxC1) coordinate[label=right:$A$](A)
   (intersection of C--A and B--auxB2) coordinate[label=below:$E$](E)
   (intersection of B--A and C--auxC2) coordinate[label=above:$F$](F)
   pic[draw,"$30^\circ$"]{angle=E--C--F}
   pic[draw,"$50^\circ$"]{angle=F--C--B}
   pic[draw,"$60^\circ$"]{angle=C--B--E}
   pic[draw,"$20^\circ$"]{angle=E--B--F}
   pic[draw,"$x$"]{angle=F--E--B};
 \draw[thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle (B) -- (E) -- (F) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can also ask Ti*k*Z to measure the angle `x`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[angle eccentricity=1.5,angle radius=1cm]
   (0,0) coordinate[label=below left:$C$] (C)
   (0,5) coordinate[label=above left:$B$] (B) 
   (10:5) coordinate (auxC1) (40:5) coordinate (auxC2) 
   ($(B)+(-10:5)$) coordinate (auxB1)
   ($(B)+(-30:5)$) coordinate (auxB2)
   (intersection of B--auxB1 and C--auxC1) coordinate[label=right:$A$](A)
   (intersection of C--A and B--auxB2) coordinate[label=below:$E$](E)
   (intersection of B--A and C--auxC2) coordinate[label=above:$F$](F)
   pic[draw,"$30^\circ$"]{angle=E--C--F}
   pic[draw,"$50^\circ$"]{angle=F--C--B}
   pic[draw,"$60^\circ$"]{angle=C--B--E}
   pic[draw,"$20^\circ$"]{angle=E--B--F}
   let \p1=($(B)-(E)$),\p2=($(F)-(E)$),
    \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)}  in
   pic[draw,"$x=\pgfmathparse{\n1-\n2}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult^\circ$",
    angle radius=2cm,angle eccentricity=1.25]{angle=F--E--B};
 \draw[thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle (B) -- (E) -- (F) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does `10:5` or `-10:5` refer to? Also, how do you draw the vertical angles at the intersection?

Comment: @Superman `(10:5)` are polar coordinates, `10` is the angle and `5` the radius. This is used to define auxiliary coordinates for "rays" with the proper slope for the intersections. The second part of the comment I do not understand.

Comment: Oh ok. Interesting about the polar coordinates representation. But anyway, I meant to say, segments BE and CF intersect. I was wondering how to draw the angles at the intersection. Finally, what is `angle eccentricity`? Also, does angle radius refer to how "big" the angle marks look?

Comment: @Superman It is always the same syntax: `pic[draw,"<text>"]{angle=<A>--<B>--<C>}`, where `A`, `B`, and `C` are the three points involved (`B` is where the angle is). `angle radius` is indeed the radius of the arc, and `angle eccentricity` controls the ration of the distance of the text from the vertex to the radius.

Comment: Also, the labels looks smaller relative to the geometric figure in the second picture compared to those in the first. How did you do this?

Comment: Oh, so the higher the `angle eccentricity`, the "farther away" the text is from the angle?

Comment: @Superman This is just because when you upload the figure it gets scaled to the width of the text here, and in the second one figure the distance between `B` and `C` is large. And yes, `the higher the angle eccentricity, the "farther away" the text is from the angle`, if you choose an `angle eccentricity` smaller than 1 the text will be inside the arc.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/C,0/pi/B}
   \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center C angle -80](B) \tkzGetPoint{BB}
   \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center B angle 80](C) \tkzGetPoint{CC}
   \tkzInterLL(B,CC)(C,BB) \tkzGetPoint{A}
   \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center C angle 30](A) \tkzGetPoint{AA}
   \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center B angle -20](A) \tkzGetPoint{AAA} 
   \tkzInterLL(B,A)(C,AA) \tkzGetPoint{F}
   \tkzInterLL(C,A)(B,AAA) \tkzGetPoint{E}  
   % drawing   
   \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
   \tkzDrawSegments(C,F B,E E,F)
   % marking
   \tkzMarkAngles[mark=none](F,E,B E,C,B C,B,F)
   \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.5](E,C,F){$30^\circ$}
   \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.5](E,B,F){$20^\circ$}
   \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.5](F,C,B){$50^\circ$}
   \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.5](C,B,E){$60^\circ$}
   \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.5](F,E,B){$x$}
   % labeling
   \tkzLabelPoints[left](B,C)
   \tkzLabelPoints[right](A)
   \tkzLabelPoints[above](F)
   \tkzLabelPoints[below](E)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]